# How do I set mdButton text to lowercase?

Tags: angular-material

As you can see from [here](https://material.angularjs.org/0.11.4/demo/button), mdButton will set your text with uppercase letters. What if I want to make lowercase?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write your own class using css **text-transform** such as,

```
.tolowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.tocapitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

And apply it to the input/button.

If you want htis behaviour throughout the system override the .md-button class in your css,

```
 .md-button {    
    text-transform: capitalize !important;/*For Lower case use lowercase*/
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this will make all the text lowercase...how do i preserve that first letter to be capitalized. For example, a button with text 'About' will become 'ABOUT' as an md-button and with the above solution become 'about'

Answer (score 3):

Remove the text-transform from `md-button` in CSS:

```css
.md-button {
  text-transform: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in XML:

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

Programmatically:

```
 mbutton.setAllCaps(false);
```

Comment: This is tagged as a javascript/html question.

Comment: @poxopox ohhh I am sorry i thought it is android question

Answer (score 0):

Neat. You can also add the bootstrap class `text-lowercase` to your button to override the defaults. To use capitalization in your button (each word to start with a capital letter), ensure that you write your button name in lowercase, then add the bootstrap class `text-capitalize` to your button. Easier that way.