# Ionic 2 button -- Text font is not uppercase (default)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

folks.
I have a little problem with an ionic 2 form. Everything looks appropriate, except for the button "Enviar".

[image: "Enviar" button screenshot]

I haven't made any changes in the button style, and the text button must appear uppercase by default.
Here's the code:

```
<button ion-button full icon-left type="submit">
<ion-icon name="send">`
Enviar
</ion-icon>
</button>
```

Thanks a lot if you can help me out!

Comment: Might be that will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728424/how-do-i-set-mdbutton-text-to-lowercase

Comment: you may find your answer here :-
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364677/ionic-v2-button-text-in-caps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text should be placed outside the icon, like this:

```
<button ion-button full icon-left type="submit">
  <ion-icon item-left name="send"></ion-icon>
  Enviar
</button>
```

You can find more information about this in the [buttons docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#icon-buttons).